# Return Variables to a Template

Tags: templates, add-on-development, module, ee3

I have created a module for **Expression Engine 3**, which includes two functions.

1. `search_form`
2. `search_results`

`search_form` returns a form into my template.

`search_entries` is *actioned* by `search_form` upon the forms submission. This function then completed my queries, returning an array of `entry_id`.

**My question, is how can I then return those entry ids back to the template, and output them through a channel entries tag?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar situation this week.
I've made two functions - one for the form template tag and second is action callback that works with form data.

In this manner I could output information with `ee()->output->show_message()`. Like this:

```
$data = array(
  'title' => 'Search Results',
  'heading' => 'Search Results',
  'content' => "content as a string. wrapped as system message"
);
ee()->output->show_message($data);
```

That was not what I was looking for :( So I've switched to post->redirect->get pattern and added another template tag for showing search results.

In general, now I have 3 methods inside base module class:

`search_form` constructs html for the form and returns it

`search_submit` is processing data passed after form submit, saves results into `$_SESSION` variable and redirects user to template with search results tag.

`search_results` reads data from `$_SESSION`, creates `$variables` array and returns it with `ee()->TMPL->parse_variables(ee()->TMPL->tagdata, $variables)`.

```
class Custom_search {
  function search_form() {
    $action_id = ee()->functions->fetch_action_id('Custom_search', 'search_form_submit');
    $form_data = array(
      'action' => ee()->functions->create_url(ee()->uri->uri_string),
      'hidden_fields' => array(
         'ACT' => $action_id,
         'return_url' => ee()->functions->create_url('template_group/search_results')
       )
    );
    $tag_data = ee()->TMPL->tagdata;
    $form = ee()->functions->form_declaration($form_data) . $tag_data . "</form>";
    return $form;
  }

  function search_form_submit() {
    //do something with input
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['custom_search']['query'] = "search query here";
    $_SESSION['custom_search']['results'] = $results;
    ee()->functions->redirect(ee()->input->post('return_url'));
  }

  function search_result() {
    session_start();
    //create $vars array from your results here
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    return ee()->TMPL->parse_variables(ee()->TMPL->tagdata, $vars);
  }
}
```

And you'll have two template files - one with search form template tag

```
{exp:custom_search:search_form}
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." name="query" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="go" />
{/exp:custom_search:search_form}
```

and another with results tag

```
{exp:custom_search:search_result}
  <p>Your query: {query}</p>
  <p>Results found: {total_results}</p>
  {results}
    <h4>{title}</h4>
    <p>{description}</p>
  {/results}
{/exp:custom_search:search_result}
```